# How to install/uninstall windows service using puppet?

Tags: windows-services, puppet

I want to install/uninstall windows service on Puppet but I cannot find a **built-in** function of doing that. I came up with the script below which works fine but it's ugly.

```
exec{ "install_service" :
    command => "${Sys32}\\cmd.exe /c installutil -i /LogFile=\"${logFile}\" \"${sourcePath}\" | exit 0",
    path => $Framework4x64,
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I tried to search for a plug-in but haven't found it yet.

Comment: When you say "install/uninstall windows service" are you referring to installing the puppet agent or another application?

Comment: I want to install another application.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's something built into Puppet. The generic way for "manually" creating a service in Windows is to use the [`sc.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) utility (note the space *after* and lack thereof *before* the `=` character):

```
exec { "install_service" :
    command => "${Sys32}\\sc.exe create MyService start= auto binPath= \"C:\\path\\to\\your.exe\"",
    path    => $Framework4x64,
    unless  => "${Sys32}\\sc.exe query MyService",
}
```

or PowerShell (preferably using the [PowerShell provider](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/powershell)):

```
exec { "install_service" :
    command  => "New-Service -Name MyService -StartupType Automatic -BinaryPathName \"C:\\path\\to\\your.exe\"",
    path     => $Framework4x64,
    provider => 'powershell',
    unless   => "Get-Service MyService; exit (1-[int]$?)",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a read of the docs for installing [packages using puppet on Windows](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/writing.html#packagepackage).

It's basically the same way as using a package resource on *nix.  Example from their docs:

Example they give:

```
package { 'mysql':
      ensure          => '5.5.16',
      source          => 'N:/packages/mysql-5.5.16-winx64.msi',
      install_options => ['INSTALLDIR=C:\mysql-5.5'],
    }
```

Comment: `package` works with msi or setup files but in my case, it's a windows service and I don't have that file. From the example, I use installutil.exe and pass in path to the file and install the service.